# Will ValueTask still be beneficial if it depends on a method that returns Task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, valuetask

Using the following methods as an example:

```cs
public async ValueTask<int> MyMethod() {
    return await GetMyIntegerWithTask();
}

public async Task<int> GetMyIntegerWithTask() {
   if (/*in hot path*/) {
      return await SynchronousMethodThatUsesTask();
   } 
   return await AsynchronousMethodThatUsesTask();
}

public Task<int> SynchronousMethodThatUsesTask() {
   int value = new Random().Next();
   return Task.FromResult(value); 
}

public async Task<int> AsynchronousMethodThatUsesTask() {
   //some asynchronous calculation 
}
```

Does using `ValueTask` as the return type of `MyMethod` still have the advantages associated with `ValueTask` because I expect that most of the time my code will execute synchronously (even though the synchronous method I'm depending on returns `Task` rather than `ValueTask`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does using ValueTask as the return type of MyMethod still have the advantages associated with ValueTask because I expect that most of the time my code will execute synchronously (even though the synchronous method I'm depending on returns Task rather than ValueTask)?

The performance benefits of `ValueTask` are minor, unless you are calling this very often. That said, yes, `ValueTask` will at the very least avoid a `Task` allocation, and in the synchronous case also avoids boxing the state machine struct onto the heap.

It would be *better* if both `GetMyIntegerWithTask` and `SynchronousMethodThatUsesTask` also use `ValueTask<int>`, but even without that `MyMethod` can use `ValueTask<int>` to avoid *some* allocations, at least.